# Cannot access non-static field in static context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I am getting an error when coding in Visual Studio 2010 stating `Cannot access non-static field _cf in static context`, can somebody please explain why I am getting this message and if possible how to resolve this issue?

**CommonFunctions.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Functions
{
    public class CommonFunctions
    {
        public string CurrentUser()
        {
            string login = HttpContext.Current.User.ToString();
            string[] usplit = login.Split('\\');
            string name = usplit[1];
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

**Team.aspx.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Team : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private readonly CommonFunctions _cf = new CommonFunctions();

        public string CurrentUser = _cf.CurrentUser();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUser))
            {
                // Do stuff here
            }
            else
            {
                // Do other stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can put the `CurrentUser` code direct into the `protected void Page_Load` function but as I need to reuse `CurrentUser` throughout the project it seems ludicrous to replicate.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Google shows 1,670,000 results for the search of your error message (i.e. "Cannot access non-static field in static context", without double quotes). Generally, this is a useful trick: take your error message, remove identifiers specific to your program (e.g. `_cf`) and feed the rest to Google. Extremely high chances are that you will get an answer right back.

Comment: Why do you mix UI.Page with ASP.MVC ? If you need access Current user use Session instead HttpContext. I suggest you to read default template project for ASP.MVC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting things up in the constructor would make more sense:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Team : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private readonly CommonFunctions _cf;

        public string CurrentUser;

        public Team() 
        {
            _cf = new CommonFunctions();
            CurrentUser = _cf.CurrentUser();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUser))
            {
                // Do stuff here
            }
            else
            {
                // Do other stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, a little bit of tweaking sorted my issue, many thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialise the current user field by calling a method on the _cf field. The two fields do not have a specific order of this execution. CurrentUser could be initialised first.